# Why data-bs-placement="right" is not working

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-5

I have a problem. When I use data-bs-placement="right in the propper it shows wrong. I changed data-bs-placement to other sides and the problem remains. Why doesn't it work?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    </head>

    <body>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" style="margin-right: 500px;" data-bs-container="body" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-placement="top" data-bs-content="Top popover">
      Popover on top
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" style="margin-right: 500px;" data-bs-container="body" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-placement="right" data-bs-content="Right popover">
      Popover on right
    </button>
   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and my js file:

```
var popoverTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="popover"]'))
var popoverList = popoverTriggerList.map(function (popoverTriggerEl) {
  return new bootstrap.Popover(popoverTriggerEl)
})
```

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0MEJ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tooltips` are displayed using `popper js` library, this library calculates the position where the `tooltip` will be displayed, meaning if the library calculates that there isn't sufficient space above or to the right of the button , the library will display the tooltip at the bottom.

You can pass a list of preferred fallback order like this:

```
  let tooltipTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]'))
  let tooltipList = tooltipTriggerList.map(function (tooltipTriggerEl) {
          return new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl, {
            fallbackPlacements: ['top', "bottom", 'right', 'left'],
          })
        })
```